# How to encode JSON byte array to BSON?

Tags: c, arrays, encoding, bson

How do I encode a byte array in JSON to BSON? (i'm making my own encoder in C, not using any library)

If I have an array that is:

```
"data":[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]
```

Where all the numbers are unsigned ints of 8 bits, it says in the http://bsonspec.org/spec.html that a binary structure should start with an int32 representing the number of bytes in the array followed by a subtype.
So the BSON representation should be something like :

```
\x04data\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06
\x07\x08\x09\x0A\x00
```

Where:

```
\x04 => indicates an array

data\x00 => name of the array (NULL-terminated)

\x14\x00\x00\x00 => total size of the array (20 in decimal)

\x0A\x00\x00\x00 => number of bytes in the array (10 in decimal)

\x00 => default subtype

\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0A => the data I want to transmit

0x00 => NULL byte that ends the array
```

Is everything okay with that encoding?

Thanks!

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry, I just want to know if everything is okay, cause the specs on the BSON site are a little confusing. And in the future, an java interpreter should be able to read that BSON data